# subversion branch merging in practice

Tags: svn, branching-and-merging

According to the [SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchemerge.basicmerging.reintegrate), the correct way to merge a feature branch back to the trunk is:

- merge the current trunk into the feature branch and fix any conflicts, tests, etc. on the feature branch
- commit the feature branch
- merge the feature branch to the trunk with the --reintegrate option
- commit the trunk

I've tried following these instructions and also this simpler approach:

- merge the feature branch to the trunk with the --reintegrate option
- commit the trunk

I can't see any obvious difference between these two, it seems the result of the merge is identical in both cases, is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

> the correct way to merge a feature branch back to the trunk

This is the correct way for pre-1.8 Subversion, obsoleted by 1.8+, In 1.8+ you have just merge branch to trunk (without obsolted `--reintegrate` option, reintegration is default style of merge now)

Comment: I presume you're referring to the version of the SVN server? Is there any easy way to find out which version I'm using?

Comment: @Don - no, about client. Server can be any of compatible to 1.8 client  version

Answer (score 1):

The end result has to be the same: all the changes that happened in trunk and in the feature branch should end up in one place.

As far as I remember the book is explaining a scenario where the feature branch is not too short-lived, and so it recommends to merge from trunk periodically, for example once a week or so. The idea is to merge relatively small chunks of changes, to spread out conflicts in small doses instead of one big monster merge with many conflicts.

If you never merged from the trunk to the feature branch, then I think it makes sense to take the 2nd option, and merge the feature branch directly into the trunk. I prefer this way, because the changes that show up in the diff are your own changes, things you did in the feature branch, so it's easy to read them, and easy to resolve conflicts. When merging from the trunk to the feature branch, those are changes by other people and might not make a lot of sense to you.